# proving $N(L_A)^\perp=Im(L_At)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T:V\to V$ be a linear map. Let $Im(T)$ be the image of $T$ and $N(T)$ be the null space of $T$.
For an $m\times n$ real matrix $A$, show that $N(L_A)^\perp=Im(L_At)$

($A^t$ denotes the transpose of A and $\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement, namely, $N(L_A)^\perp=\{v\in V|<v,s>=0\quad \forall s\in N(L_A)\}$ and $L_A$ denotes a linear operator such that $L_A(x)=Ax\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ )

I have shown $Im(L_At)\subseteq N(L_A)^\perp$ in the following way:
Let $x\in Im(L_At)$ be given. That is, there exists  $y\in \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $x=A^ty$.
Note that $\forall z\in N(L_A),\ <x,z>=<A^t y,z>=(A^t y)^t z=y^t Az=0$ so $x\in N(L_A)^\perp$.

But I haven't been able to show the other way, which is $N(L_A)^\perp\subseteq Im(L_At)$. I cannot use the fact $rankA=rankA^t$ here because the ultimate goal of this problem is to show $rankA=rankA^t$ using $N(L_A)^\perp=Im(L_At)$.. Please help? Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use dimension arguments; a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space with the same dimension must be the whole space.

Comment: I think you can check $N(A^t)=$Im$(A)^\perp$. From this you can also get your ultimate goal and it is easy.